# Dictionary form of verb followed by に

Tags: grammar, meaning, particles, particle-に

I've recently begun noticing that occasionally I'll see a dictionary form of the verb followed by the particle に, for example:

> 1.)まだ学校へ行く**には**早い時間です。 It's still too early to go to school.

I've been kind of confused by it since from my experience normally the dictionary form of verbs are followed by a nominalizer の　or こと before a particle. For example:

> 2.)まだ学校へ行く**のは**早い時間です。
>
> 3.)まだ学校へ行く**のに**早い時間です。

What is the general function of に directly following the dictionary form of a verb and how is it generally used? How would sentence 1's meaning differ from sentences 2 and 3?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5069/7810, http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13057/7810, http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24326/7810 And I'm surprised I couldn't find a 100% duplicate of this question on this site...

Comment: 「まだ学校へ行くのは早い時間です。」は、文法的にちょっと怪しいような・・・

Comment: @broccoliforest Thanks for sharing the links, I did a bit of a search too expecting to find someone asking the exact same thing.

Comment: @choco I thought the grammar was a little unusual too, this sentence was actually from the core6k sentences from this company http://iknow.jp/ I believe they were formerly known as smart.fm. EDIT: Nevermind I had actually misread your response, the sentence 「まだ学校へ行くには早い時間です」 was from iknow.jp。　「まだ学校へ行くのは早い時間です。」　was what I came up with to try and figure out the difference in nuances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, には means "in order to" or "for the purpose of". In sentences that use this expression, the predicate often expresses the necessity for or importance of using a specific means. You can use the nominalizer の if you choose to, and it won't change the meaning: まだ学校へ行く**のには**早い時間です。

This には can also come after a noun, as in このかばんは長旅には便利だ (This bag is suitable for long trips).

There are many other expressions involving に that can attach to verbs (or i-adjectives and other interesting things) including:

> にしては
>
> にちがいない
>
> に当たって
>
> にもかかわらず
>
> に従って
>
> に過ぎない
>
> につれて

Source: A Dictionary of Intermediate Japanese Grammar