# Understanding the も in 見るも

Tags: grammar, idioms, particle-も

> その日。彼女のもとに、招かれざる客が現れた。
>
> 見る**も**巨大な鉄の塊。長い手足の歪な人型。
>
> そんな異形共が、彼女の領域を侵したのである。

What would be the function of the bold も?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

見るも is better remembered as a fixed adverbial idiom "patently", "manifestly" but usually qualifies what is shocking at first glance.

This phrase cooccurs with following adjectives across the [BCCWJ](https://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/):

| word | count |
| --- | --- |
| 無残/無惨/無慙/無ざん/むざん | 32 |
| 哀れ/あわれ | 7 |
| 恐ろしい/おそろしい | 5 |
| おぞましい | 4 |
| 痛々しい | 3 |
| あさましい | 1 |
| 嫌 | 1 |
| 悲しい | 1 |
| きれい | 1 |
| 燦爛 | 1 |
| 獰猛 | 1 |
| 悲惨 | 1 |
| まばゆい | 1 |
| まぶしい | 1 |
| みじめ | 1 |

(**Edit**: a few additions during a more complete query.)

So that 見るも巨大な could be translated "awfully massive" or "monstrously huge".

This grammar belongs to the historical 連体形準体法, attaching nominal particles directly to a verb, from the time when today's dictionary form represented [some sort of participle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attributive_verb). It is only surviving in proverbs and a few fixed expressions, such as [[verb] + には](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13057/7810), [[verb] + がいい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36714/7810), and [思うに/言うに...](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29418/7810)

Comment: How do you use BCCWJ to search for collocations and their frequencies? I tried the 『梵天』（登録不要）version but what I got was usage instances.

Comment: @EddieKal I have a subscription to 中納言 (free). With that you can query by morphological information and download the data to count frequencies.